# What is the difference between .hover and :hover?

Tags: css, hover

I was digging some css codes written by someone and I found this:

```
li.hover, li:hover {

}
```

Is there any difference between .hover and :hover?
Maybe some browsers act differently for `hover`?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:hover` is a [psuedo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) while `.hover` is a selector for the class `hover`. These symbols (`:` and `.`) don't change meaning from any other CSS selector construct: see the [W3C CSS Level 3 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) for all the details.

Presumably there is some JavaScript to toggle the `hover` class, perhaps because of lack of `:hover` support for LI elements in a "legacy" browser. I know that IE5/6 (*ick!*) only supported `:hover` for links, however:

- [*"Modern" GUI browsers correctly support `:hover`*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

(And, as always, make sure the page is *not* in "quirksmode" :-)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

`.hover` is just a class name (possibly used to mean "something I [the coder] want to look the same as a hovered item", whereas `:hover` is the psuedo-class for when the mouse is over it. (Personally I use `.hl` instead of `.hover` for something like that)

Comment: So I dont' have to write a.hover, a:hover together? It's enougn having only :hover?!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek: That is *not* necessarily correct. Assuming the `hover` class is added with javascript and you want as much browser support as you can get, you still need both! `:hover` is not supported on a lot of elements, including `li`, in older browsers. [pst's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722199/398242) explains it.

Comment: Yeah, but there comes a time where you have to stop babying older browsers. How can we move forward if we cling to decade-old software?

Comment: @Kolink: At my job, I have to support at least IE7. We do a ton of government work where our clients are on WinXP systems or can't even upgrade to IE8 from 7. In a perfect world, all browsers would be awesome but that's not reality, is it? If `.hover` is the only thing making something accessible in IE7, then I need it. (We did finally drop IE6 a couple years ago however)

Comment: @Madmartigan I got it, thank you! You are correct, sometimes we solve such problems with javascript, so then i need .hover or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

`.hover` is a normal class name like any other class name, it has no special meaning.
`:hover` is the `hover` pseudo-class which you cannot create yourself, which is only applied when the user hovers over an element with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: one's a class (that's `.hover`) and the other's a pseudo-class (`:hover`). The pseudo-class will be matched when the mouse is over the element, and the class will be matched when the element has that class.

Presumably, the class is added by JavaScript. This could be for compatibility (some version of IE, I believe IE6 or IE7, only supports `:hover` on `<a>` elements) or it could be for extra features (sticky highlighting, for example).